# How to avoid hard-coding navigation in a SwiftUI app using NavigationSplitView, NavigationStack, and NavigationPath

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I'm trying to design an extensible navigation system using `NavigationSplitView`, `NavigationStack`, and `NavigationPath`.

Definition of a route:

```
struct Route: Identifiable, Hashable {

    let id: String
    let hashValue: Int
    let title: String
    let content: () -> AnyView

    init<Content: View>(title: String, content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.id = title
        self.hashValue = UUID().hashValue
        self.content = { AnyView(content()) }
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(hashValue)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
        lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}
```

NavigationPath wrapper.

```
final class Navigation: ObservableObject {

    @Published var path = NavigationPath()

    func push(_ route: Route) {
        path.append(route)
    }

    func pop() {
        path.removeLast(1)
    }

    func root() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }

    func root(_ route: Route) {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
        path.append(route)
    }
}
```

With all the heavy lifting happening in the split and stack views.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var navigation: Navigation = .init()
    @ObservedObject var routes: Routes = .init()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationSplitView {
            sidebar
        } detail: {
            detail
        }
    }

    private var sidebar: some View {

        NavigationStack {

            List {

                ForEach(routes.items) { item in

                    Button {
                        navigation.root()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Home")
                    }

                    Button {
                        navigation.root(item)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var detail: some View {

        NavigationStack(path: $navigation.path) {
            Group {
                Text("Root View")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Route.self, destination: { route in
                route.content()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This all seems to work reasonably well, but I have some questions.

1. When I pop all the views on iOS I end up in the root view. Is this correct or typical behaviour? It doesn't look so bad on the iPad, but feels odd on iOS.
2. Watching the memory usage after adding many views and then popping them all, it seems higher. Are there any real memory leaks with this?
3. Is there a better way of wrapping a view such that it's not created when the menu is created but provides the same flexibility. My approach uses a closure and `AnyView` and I'm not sure if this will cause problems.
4. Have I missed some obvious way of achieving this extensible architecture using built-in capabilities?

Comment: Switch the ObservedObject to StateObject. Misuse is a typical reason for a leak. Also AnyView is highly discouraged, views should be in a ViewBuilder

Comment: @loremipsum I appreciate the AnyView issues, but how do I achieve the decoupled aspect by using @ViewBuilder?

Comment: This setup just doesn’t work with SwiftUI. You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Comment: There are plenty of articles around that show how to store viewbuilders. And you really don't need to. Your .navigationDestination closure can build a view based on the route.

Comment: @hayesk I get the storage of a ViewBuilder but I still don't see how to achieve what I want. The .navigationDestination modifier takes a type not a route. Happy for you to post code as an answer and I can evaluate that.

Comment: @ScottMcKenzie  navigationState can also bind to an item, such as your route. The closure can then evaluate the item and choose return the appropriate destiation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(item:destination:)# has a code sample.